# Evaluate Method XPath in Chrome

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, jscript

I'm working with CRM Dynamics 2011.
I have this code

```
var roles = oXml.selectNodes("//BusinessEntity/q1:name");
```

where oXml is my xml, obtained with a XMLHttpRequest.

I need that my code works in Chrome but it seems like chrome doesn't support select nodes.

I try with

```
var roles = document.evaluate( "//BusinessEntity/q1:name", oXml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

And it doesn't work. I don't know what i'm missing.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same problem, and I think that I have found the solution:
The reason why your code doesn't work is the following: you doesn't specify proper XML namespace resolver. It means that Chrome or Firefox cannot understand how to find element "q1:name".

Below you can find correct version for getting name of business entity in CRM 2011:

```
function nsResolver(prefix) {
  var ns = {
    'q1': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'
  };

  return ns[prefix] || null;
}

var roles = node.evaluate("//BusinessEntity/q1:name", oXml, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

More info about namespace resolving can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver

Hope this helps!